# MongoDB Test Failover with MongoCLI

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying out create a script for a failure scenario in our project and I want to call the "Test Failover" process from Atlas UI from the CI. I looked through the documentation and there doesn't seem to be any info about the test failover using MongoCLI.

So is there any way I could run this from a command interface?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, found out I can do this via API:
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/clusters-test-failover